# Get a list of partial lists

Tags: scala

So I have a list of elements and I want to get a list of all lists which can be generated by selecting an arbitrary number of elements from the original list.

For this input:
`val input = List('a','b','a')`

I expect this output:
`val input = List(List(), List('a'), List('b'), List('a','a'), List('a', 'b'), List('a','b','a'))`

Note that I don't want to include `List('b','b')` since 'b' is only present once in the original collection and I dont't want `List('b','a')` since it is already included in a different order.

I have found several solutions of similar problems based on `subsets` method of the Set class or `combinations` method but none that fulfills all of my requirements:

- Allow for duplicates in the original collection
- Have "sublists" of arbitrary size
- Exclude "sublists" which are already present in a different order.

Comment: I believe you want `permutations`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `combinations()` will do what you want. All sub-lists are presented in increasing order.

```
val input = List('a','b','a')

(0 to input.length).flatMap(input.combinations)
//res0: IndexedSeq[List[Char]] =
//      Vector(List(), List(a), List(b), List(a, a), List(a, b), List(a, a, b))
```